# TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined (Gatsby error)

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm getting an error that I wasn't getting yesterday and I cannot figure out what the issue is.

I've tried updating npm and gatsby-cli and Ive cleared all caches.

Project.js file:

```
import React from 'react'
import Image from 'gatsby-image'
import styles from '../../css/tour.module.css'
import {FaMap} from 'react-icons/fa'
import AniLink from 'gatsby-plugin-transition-link/AniLink'

const Project = ({project}) => {
    const {title,description,updated,slug,images} = project
    console.log(images);
    return <article>this is a single project</article>
}

export default Project
```

I am trying to see the array of images in the console but I'm getting this error for everything I try to assign to the project variable

```
Project.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
    at Project (Project.js:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16319)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:18734)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:20083)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:363)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:412)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:467)
    at beginWork$$1 (react-dom.development.js:25729)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:24637)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:24613)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:24181)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:23589)
    at scheduleRootUpdate (react-dom.development.js:26944)
    at updateContainerAtExpirationTime (react-dom.development.js:26972)
    at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:27074)
    at react-dom.development.js:27662
    at unbatchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:24374)
    at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (react-dom.development.js:27661)
    at render (react-dom.development.js:27804)
    at app.js:40
```

This error is only showing up in the chrome console, the build is successful in my VS terminal.

Comment: Can you share the file where you imported the Project component

Comment: try default like `const Project = ({ project = {} }) => {` may be during your initial render props for Project were not created to have `project` in it.